# FreeText in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-extensions

I am trying to implement search and I am using entity framework core.
I tried using the following query-

```
var users = await context.Users.Where(u => EF.Functions.FreeText(u.UserName, searchString)).ToListAsync();
```

This query is throwing the following error -

> InvalidOperationException: The 'FreeText' method is not supported
>   because the query has switched to client-evaluation.

Model

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName{ get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
  [HttpGet("search/{searchString}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchUser(string searchString)
    {
        var users=await repository.Search(searchString);
        return Ok(users);
    }
```

I even tried switching u.UserName with "UserName" as some answers to similar questions suggested but got the same result. I'd be glad if someone could help me with this.

Comment: the docs say `This can happen if the query contains one or more expressions that could not be translated to the store.`

Comment: Yeah, although I do not understand why that must be happening. If  instead of freetext I just use `u.UserName == "text"` it works properly as an exact search, which means at least that I am referencing the column properly, however I am not sure why the freetext method is not giving the required search query.

Comment: The log gives the error `The LINQ expression 'where __Functions_0.FreeText([a].UserName, "test")' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.`

Comment: Are you running against SqlServer database? And not against InMemory for instance (for unit testing or something)?

Comment: @IvanStoev Running against SqlLite.

Comment: @Nemesis That should explain the exception, because `FreeText` is SqlServer db provider specific functions extension, hence is not recognized (translated) by other db providers.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the information. That's a bit disappointing. I guess then there's no general EF method to implement full search? Since while changing providers for deployment doesn't require changing any other methods.

Comment: @Nemesis Unfortunately. I also find strange the decision to allow db providers extending `EF.Functions` with their specific methods, which is against the "db agnostic" idea of ORM, but it is what it is.